# Python import packages

Tags: python, import, module

Does anyone know how to use pip install for pdftable? I have tried pulling it from github and that pip install does not work. I have also tried using pdftable version 0.0.3 all the way up to version 1.0 and none of them work is it because the versions of pdftables are all old versions that are no longer working?

Comment: Could you please specify from which Github repository have you cloned?

Comment: Have you tried installing package(tar.gz file) and python setup.py install  ...? or you can get the wheel file and install through pip

Comment: Please read [ask]...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it I just had to pull the zip file in, but now I have another problem which I could use help with, my code is as follows:

```
c = pdftables_api.Client('My API Key from github')
c.xlsx(r'C:\Users\test\Documents\Excel files\test.pdf', 'output.xlsx')
```

after I run this i get the following error:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pdftables.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api?key=11799n7n515r&format=xlsx-multiple (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))

I dont know how to get around this so any suggestions would be great!

Comment: seems like api_key did not work. Are you sure that the api key is correct? or are you running this behind any firewall ? Sometimes that may also cause issues in connecting.

Comment: I will have to check, but as far as I know I am not behind a firewall.